# Random names instead of patterns in particle.js

Tags: javascript, particles.js

Before anything, I have no idea what I'm doing but I was wondering if it was possible to use vincentgarreaus' particles with names instead of patterns?

I managed to edit particle.js and add a function that randomly picks a name and it replaces the circles for the names but my problem is that while moving the names change too fast in the same particle. If I set it to static it works as intended but I want them moving.

Is it possible?

What I did is going to [VG website](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) > inspect element > ctrl P > particle.js > Line 426 and pasted this "code" > ctrl S to save

```
function PlayerSelector1() {
  var word = ['player1', 'player2', 'player3', 'player4', 'player5', 'player6'];
  var random = word[Math.floor(Math.random() * word.length)];
  return random;
}

    switch(p.shape){

      case "circle":
          var context = pJS.canvas.ctx.canvas.getContext("2d");
          var xtxx = PlayerSelector1();
          context.beginPath();
          context.fillStyle = "black";
          context.fillText(xtxx, p.x, p.y);
          context.fill();
          break;
```

I have nothing to offer for your help but you will have my eternal gratitude

Comment: It seems like you're almost there with your attempt, but what is your issue? What isn't working?

Comment: Names change too fast to the point they are unreadable, it's like while the particles are moving PlayerSelector1 function is being continuously executed

Answer (score 0):

You can't create text particles using particles.js natively, but you can use [tsParticles](https://particles.js.org) instead which support text particles.

This is how you can achieve it:

```js
// keeping your function, it's fine
function PlayerSelector1() {
  var word = ["player1", "player2", "player3", "player4", "player5", "player6"];
  var random = word[Math.floor(Math.random() * word.length)];
  return random;
}

// basic particles configuration, used for example
tsParticles.load("tsparticles", {
  background: {
    color: "#000"
  },
  particles: {
    number: {
      value: 10
    },
    move: {
      enable: true
    },
    size: {
      value: 30
    },
    shape: {
      type: "text",
      options: {
        text: {
          value: PlayerSelector1()
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

For using tsParticles you can read the instructions on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles)

This is your working demo on CodePen, using the config shown above: https://codepen.io/matteobruni/pen/oNymXmy?editors=0010

Every time you call the `tsParticles.load` function, the player will change.

Comment: Thanks!! that looks really close to what I was trying to achieve!! What if I want it to display more than one name at the same time? Should I add more texts values?

Comment: You can use an array instead of a single string. For multiline text there’s a plugin for that